# Attempt to invoke virtual method 'void android.widget.TextView.setOnClickListener on a null object reference

Tags: android-studio, kotlin

I'm fairly new to coding in kotlin and Android studio and I'm struggling with something :

"java.lang.RuntimeException: Unable to start activity ComponentInfo{com.example.register/com.example.register.LoginActivity}: java.lang.NullPointerException: Attempt to invoke virtual method 'void android.widget.TextView.setOnClickListener(android.view.View$OnClickListener)' on a null object reference"

I created a button on my XLM file (at the end of the file, named gotoLogin) :

```
<?xml version="1.0" encoding="utf-8"?>
<androidx.constraintlayout.widget.ConstraintLayout xmlns:android="http://schemas.android.com/apk/res/android"
    xmlns:app="http://schemas.android.com/apk/res-auto"
    xmlns:tools="http://schemas.android.com/tools"
    android:layout_width="match_parent"
    android:layout_height="match_parent"
    tools:context=".MainActivity">

    <TextView
        android:layout_width="wrap_content"
        android:layout_height="wrap_content"
        app:layout_constraintTop_toTopOf="parent"
        app:layout_constraintBottom_toTopOf="@+id/tvEmail"
        android:text="Register"
        android:textSize="22sp"
        android:textColor="@color/black"
        app:layout_constraintStart_toStartOf="parent"
        app:layout_constraintEnd_toEndOf="parent"/>

<com.google.android.material.textfield.TextInputLayout
    android:id="@+id/tvEmail"
    android:layout_width="match_parent"
    app:layout_constraintTop_toTopOf="parent"
    app:layout_constraintBottom_toBottomOf="parent"
    app:layout_constraintStart_toStartOf="parent"
    app:layout_constraintEnd_toEndOf="parent"
    android:layout_marginStart="30dp"
    android:hint="Enter Email"
    android:layout_marginEnd="30dp"
    android:layout_height="wrap_content">
    <EditText
        android:id="@+id/editEmail"
        android:layout_width="match_parent"
        android:layout_height="wrap_content"
        android:inputType="text"/>
</com.google.android.material.textfield.TextInputLayout>

    <com.google.android.material.textfield.TextInputLayout
        android:layout_width="match_parent"
        android:id="@+id/tvPassword"
        app:layout_constraintTop_toBottomOf="@+id/tvEmail"
        app:layout_constraintStart_toStartOf="parent"
        app:layout_constraintEnd_toEndOf="parent"
        android:layout_marginStart="30dp"
        android:layout_marginTop="20dp"
        android:hint="Enter Password"
        android:layout_marginEnd="30dp"
        android:layout_height="wrap_content">
        <EditText
            android:id="@+id/editPassword"
            android:layout_width="match_parent"
            android:layout_height="wrap_content"
            android:inputType="textPassword"/>
    </com.google.android.material.textfield.TextInputLayout>
    <Button
        android:id="@+id/clkRegister"
        android:layout_width="match_parent"
        android:layout_height="wrap_content"
        android:text="Register"
        android:textColor="@color/white"
        app:layout_constraintStart_toStartOf="parent"
        app:layout_constraintEnd_toEndOf="parent"
        app:layout_constraintTop_toBottomOf="@+id/tvPassword"
        android:layout_margin="30dp"
        android:background="@color/colorAccent"/>

    <Button
        android:id="@+id/gotoLogin"
        android:layout_width="wrap_content"
        android:text="Login ?"
        android:textColor="@color/white"
        app:layout_constraintBottom_toBottomOf="parent"
        app:layout_constraintStart_toStartOf="parent"
        app:layout_constraintEnd_toEndOf="parent"
        android:padding="10dp"
        android:layout_height="wrap_content"/>

</androidx.constraintlayout.widget.ConstraintLayout>
```

and added the option to go from my MainActivity to the LoginActivity if the button was pressed :

```
class MainActivity : AppCompatActivity() {
    private lateinit var auth: FirebaseAuth
    override fun onCreate(savedInstanceState: Bundle?) {
        super.onCreate(savedInstanceState)
        setContentView(R.layout.activity_main)

        auth = FirebaseAuth.getInstance();
        val nameBtnRegister = findViewById<Button>(R.id.clkRegister)
        val nameEdtEmail = findViewById<EditText>(R.id.editEmail)
        val nameEdtPwd = findViewById<EditText>(R.id.editPassword)
        val nameGotoLogin = findViewById<TextView>(R.id.gotoLogin)

        //Register the user
        nameBtnRegister.setOnClickListener {
            if (nameEdtEmail.text.trim().toString().isNotEmpty() || nameEdtPwd.text.trim()
                    .toString().isNotEmpty()
            ) {
                createUser(nameEdtEmail.text.trim().toString(), nameEdtPwd.text.trim().toString())

            } else {
                Toast.makeText(this, "Input Required", Toast.LENGTH_LONG).show()
            }
        }

        //Go to Login page
        nameGotoLogin.setOnClickListener {
            val intent = Intent(this,LoginActivity::class.java);
            startActivity(intent)
        }
```

But once I added this option, I got my error.
In case, here is my LoginActivity :

```
class LoginActivity : AppCompatActivity() {
    private lateinit var auth: FirebaseAuth;
    override fun onCreate(savedInstanceState: Bundle?) {
        super.onCreate(savedInstanceState)
        setContentView(R.layout.activity_login)

        auth = FirebaseAuth.getInstance();
        val btnLogin = findViewById<Button>(R.id.btnLogin)
        val editTextEmail = findViewById<EditText>(R.id.editTextEmail)
        val editTextPassword = findViewById<EditText>(R.id.editTextPassword)
        val tvRegister = findViewById<TextView>(R.id.tvRegister)

        tvRegister.setOnClickListener {
            val intent = Intent(this, MainActivity::class.java);
            startActivity(intent)
        }


        btnLogin.setOnClickListener {

            if(editTextEmail.text.trim().toString().isNotEmpty() || editTextPassword.text.trim().toString().isNotEmpty()){
                signInUser(editTextEmail.text.trim().toString(), editTextPassword.text.trim().toString());
            }else{
                Toast.makeText(this,"Input required",Toast.LENGTH_LONG).show();
            }

        }


    }

    fun signInUser(email:String, password: String){

        auth.signInWithEmailAndPassword(email,password)
            .addOnCompleteListener (this) { task ->

                if(task.isSuccessful){
                    val intent = Intent(this, HomeActivity::class.java);
                    startActivity(intent)
                }else{
                    Toast.makeText(this," Error !! "+task.exception, Toast.LENGTH_LONG).show()
                }

            }

    }
}
```

And the XML file :

```
<?xml version="1.0" encoding="utf-8"?>
<androidx.constraintlayout.widget.ConstraintLayout xmlns:android="http://schemas.android.com/apk/res/android"
    xmlns:app="http://schemas.android.com/apk/res-auto"
    xmlns:tools="http://schemas.android.com/tools"
    android:layout_width="match_parent"
    android:layout_height="match_parent"
    tools:context=".LoginActivity">
    <TextView
        android:layout_width="wrap_content"
        app:layout_constraintStart_toStartOf="parent"
        app:layout_constraintEnd_toEndOf="parent"
        android:text="Login"
        android:textColor="#000"
        android:textSize="22sp"
        app:layout_constraintTop_toTopOf="parent"
        app:layout_constraintBottom_toTopOf="@+id/textInputEmail"
        android:layout_height="wrap_content"/>

    <com.google.android.material.textfield.TextInputLayout
        android:layout_width="match_parent"
        android:layout_height="wrap_content"
        app:layout_constraintTop_toTopOf="parent"
        android:hint="Enter Email"
        android:layout_marginStart="30dp"
        android:layout_marginEnd="30dp"
        android:id="@+id/textInputEmail"
        app:layout_constraintBottom_toBottomOf="parent"
        app:layout_constraintStart_toStartOf="parent"
        app:layout_constraintEnd_toEndOf="parent">
        <EditText
            android:id="@+id/editTextEmail"
            android:layout_width="match_parent"
            android:layout_height="wrap_content"/>
    </com.google.android.material.textfield.TextInputLayout>


    <com.google.android.material.textfield.TextInputLayout
        android:layout_width="match_parent"
        android:layout_height="wrap_content"
        app:layout_constraintTop_toBottomOf="@+id/textInputEmail"
        android:hint="Enter Password"
        android:layout_marginStart="30dp"
        android:layout_marginEnd="30dp"
        android:id="@+id/textInputPassword"
        android:layout_marginTop="20dp"
        app:layout_constraintStart_toStartOf="parent"
        app:layout_constraintEnd_toEndOf="parent">
        <EditText
            android:id="@+id/editTextPassword"
            android:inputType="textPassword"
            android:layout_width="match_parent"
            android:layout_height="wrap_content"/>
    </com.google.android.material.textfield.TextInputLayout>

    <Button
        android:id="@+id/btnLogin"
        android:layout_width="match_parent"
        app:layout_constraintStart_toStartOf="parent"
        app:layout_constraintEnd_toEndOf="parent"
        android:layout_margin="30dp"
        android:background="@color/colorAccent"
        android:text="Login"
        android:textColor="#fff"
        app:layout_constraintTop_toBottomOf="@+id/textInputPassword"
        android:layout_height="wrap_content"/>

    <TextView
        android:id="@+id/tvRegister"
        android:layout_width="wrap_content"
        android:layout_height="wrap_content"
        app:layout_constraintBottom_toBottomOf="parent"
        app:layout_constraintStart_toStartOf="parent"
        app:layout_constraintEnd_toEndOf="parent"
        android:text="Register ?"
        android:textColor="@color/colorPrimaryDark"
        android:padding="10dp"
        />

</androidx.constraintlayout.widget.ConstraintLayout>
```

Thank you for your time

Comment: Did you declare clkRegister in your xml? since I don't see other views except gotoLogin

Comment: I updated my post with the whole XML file

Comment: could you share the the updated code of LoginActivity with xml ?

Comment: Update added (both Activity and XML)

Answer (score 0):

I think you messed up with TextView to Button, so now need to change:

```
auth = FirebaseAuth.getInstance();
    val nameBtnRegister = findViewById<Button>(R.id.clkRegister)
    val nameEdtEmail = findViewById<EditText>(R.id.editEmail)
    val nameEdtPwd = findViewById<EditText>(R.id.editPassword)
    val nameGotoLogin = findViewById<TextView>(R.id.gotoLogin) // change here to Button not TextView
```

I think it should be this:

```
val nameGotoLogin = findViewById<Button> (R.id.gotoLogin)
```

Because it is button in main_activity.xml, not a textview.